# Computer Dies While In Incognito Mode

Tags: shutdown, browser-tabs, tabs, chromebook, private-browsing

I open an incognito tab (on my friend's Chromebook) and I was wondering if it would be open when the computer is turned on.

I am aware that after a computer crashes the incognito tab will be gone but what about after the computer dies?

Comment: Panicked & worried. I hope people are online right now.

Comment: what do you mean by `and I was wondering if it would be open when the computer is turned on.`???

Comment: what do you mean by computer dies? hard disk failure? CPU meltdown? Battery dead?

Comment: Perhaps it's obvious, but stop looking at stuff you'd feel bad about others seeing, especially when using other's computers. I assume it's possible you could have been searching for a "gift" for your friend, but the more likely reasons for your panic typically come with a greatly increased risk of malware, and it's poor manners to abuse others devices with this.

Answer (score 2):

If the Chromebook dies it's the same thing as if it would crash (even if you can revive it), that simple.